# Why is my forecast function in R not taking into account the upward trend of the data

Tags: r, forecasting

I am trying to create a forecast on a monthly time serie with various confidence interval.

I have data with clear upward trend although it is not always going up month after month.
For some reason, when I plot the result of my forecast function, the model does not take into account the upward trend. It only starts to draw the interval confidence from the last point and goes upward and downward in a very symetric and horizontal way

I've tried various forecast models but can't seem to find a one that takes into the upward trend.

```
library("forecast")
data<-read.csv(file="mydata.csv",sep=";",row.names=1,header=TRUE)

data<-ts(data, start=c(2018,8), frequency=12)

myforecast<-forecast(data, h=36, level=c(0.90,0.80,0.7, 0.60))  
head(myforecast)  
plot(myforecast)
```

CSV file data below:

```
date;Metric  
1;8127  
2;9088  
3;9801  
4;11535  
5;11657  
6;12714  
7;11908  
8;12802
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you only have 8 observations

Comment: I have 8 months of data. I can have it daily if that helps @Dason